# GNU Makefile default value variables with target files in their name

Tags: c, makefile, u-boot

I'm trying to add a variable to the U-Boot project's Makefiles.
In most targets the value does not need to be redefined and can stay the default value of /dev/null but for some targets, it needs to be defined to another value.

I'm able to achieve the second part of that task but unfortunately I'm not able to set a default value for targets that do not define that variable.

```
MKIMAGEOUTPUT_$(@F) ?= /dev/null

quiet_cmd_mkimage = MKIMAGE $@
cmd_mkimage = $(objtree)/tools/mkimage $(MKIMAGEFLAGS_$(@F)) -d $< $@ \
    $(if $(KBUILD_VERBOSE:1=), >$(MKIMAGEOUTPUT_$(@F)))
```

No I have only a few targets that need to overwrite the value of `/dev/null`.
I achieve this by adding the following line.

```
MKIMAGEOUTPUT_SPL = SPL.log
```

But for all other targets, the `MKIMAGEOUTPUT_target` variable is empty.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I just found the solution myself.
The following lines do what I wanted.

```
MKIMAGEOUTPUT ?= /dev/null

quiet_cmd_mkimage = MKIMAGE $@
cmd_mkimage = $(objtree)/tools/mkimage $(MKIMAGEFLAGS_$(@F)) -d $< $@ \
    $(if $(KBUILD_VERBOSE:1=), >$(MKIMAGEOUTPUT))
```

Plus adding the target specific value:

```
SPL: MKIMAGEOUTPUT = SPL.log
```